# Doctrine 2: How can extend entity with sql code column?

Tags: sql, doctrine-orm, native-sql, customcolumn

I have entity

```
mh\BTBundle\Entity\Post:
    type: entity
    table: post
    repositoryClass: mh\BTBundle\Repository\PostRepository
    fields:
        id:
            id: true
            type: integer
            unsigned: true
            nullable: false
            generator:
                strategy: IDENTITY
        title:
            type: string
            length: 255
            nullable: false
        content:
            type: text
            nullable: false
        isModered:
            type: boolean
            nullable: false
        isPublished:
            type: boolean
            nullable: false
        pubDate:
            type: datetime
            nullable: false
```

and now once at 1 minute cron call script, that set isPublished = true if post have isModered = true and pubDate < :now.

```
$this->getEM()->createQueryBuilder()
            ->update('BTBundle:Post p')
            ->set('p.isPublished', 'true')
            ->where('p.pubDate < :date AND p.isModered = true')
            ->setParameter(':date', new \DateTime())
            ->getQuery()->execute();
```

But i whant to define custom column isPublished with return true if SQL (`p.pubDate < CURDATE() AND p.isModered = 1`). How can i make it?

i whant to use

```
$posts = $this->getRepository('Post')->findBy(array(
            'user' => $user,
            'isPublished' => true,
        ));
```

instead of

```
$this->getEM()->createQueryBuilder()
                ->select('p')
                ->from('BTBundle:Post', 'p')
                ->where('p.isModered = true')
                ->andWhere('p.pubDate < :date')
                ->andWhere('p.user = :user')
                ->setParameter(':date', new \DateTime())
                ->setParameter(':user', $user)
                ->getQuery()->execute();
```

Comment: have you try: ->where('p.pubDate < CURDATE() AND p.isModered = 1')

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to create a computed [column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). So something like this.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Example
(
    ExampleId int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
    Value1 INT
    Value2 INT
    ComputedCol AS Value1 + Value2
);
```

You can use any valid SQL logic in the AS statement.